# Get connection_refused when redirect trafic to my backend on kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I have a deployment with frontend in react deployed on nginx container, backend in java deployed in tomcat container and a mariadb database.

I would like to deploy my application on kubernetes but I have a problem with redirecting the trafic to my backend.
When deploying with docker-compose everything works fine but when I do the same on kubernetes I get always an error when the trafic is redirected to the backend `connection_refused` and I think that it is because of my `proxy_pass` instruction in my nginx config file

```
version: "3"

services:
  db-svc:
    image: mariadb:10.8
    container_name: db-svc
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MARIADB_USER: "dbuser"
      MARIADB_DATABASE: "mydb"
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: "dbpassword"
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
    networks:
      - myapp-net
    volumes:
      - myapp-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql

  frontend-svc:
    image: myprivate.registry.local/myapp-front:2.0
    container_name: frontend-svc
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./myapp/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./myapp/ssl/myapp_certificate.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/mypp_certificate.pem
    networks:
      - myapp-net
    links:
      - backend-svc

  backend-svc:
    image: myprivate.registry.local/myapp-back:2.1.0
    container_name: backend-svc
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: "myapp"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://db-svc:3306/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: "dbuser"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: "dbpassword"
    links:
      - db-svc
    networks:
      - myapp-net
  busybox:
    image: yauritux/busybox-curl:latest
    container_name: busybox
    command: sleep 10000
    networks:
      - myapp-net

networks:
  myapp-net:

volumes:
  myapp-db-vol:
```

my nginx config is the following

```
server {
    if ($host = myapp.mydomain.local) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

  listen 80;
  server_name myapp.mydomain.local;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
  server {
  listen 9090 ssl;
  server_name myapp.mydomain.local;
  
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/myapp_certificate.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/myapp_certificate.pem;

  location / {
  proxy_pass http://backend-svc:8080;

  }
}

  server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name myapp.mydomain.local;
  
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/myapp_certificate.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/myapp_certificate.pem;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

  }
}
```

When connecting to the frontend I have a login page after entering credentials I am redirected to port 9090 which is defined into my nginx config and redirected to the backend

When I convert this configuration to kubernetes I have always `connection_refused` on the backend side and nothing appears on my logs

On kubernetes I configured all components and all my deployments, configmap, statefulset etc... are successfully deployed, no problem on logs also but I can't get the whole application working because of the redirection error I get.

myapp-front-configmap:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myapp-front-cm
  namespace: myapp
data:
  myapp.conf: |
    server {

      listen 80;
      server_name _;

      location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }
    server {
      listen 9090 ;
      server_name _;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp-back-svc:8080;
      }
    }
```

As yo can see I kept the proxy_pass instruction to redirect to `service` component

myapp-ingress:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-front-ingress
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myapp.mydomain.local
      secretName: myapp-front-tls
  rules:
    - host: myapp.mydomain.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-front-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

frontend service

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: myapp-front
  name: myapp-front-svc
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  ports:
    - name: 443-443
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
    - name: 80-80
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    - name: 9090-9090
      port: 9090
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: myapp-front
  type: LoadBalancer
```

the backend has a deployment and a ClusterIP service type, I don't need to expose the service as it's only an internal one, but I have always connection refused when I am redirected to the backend.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: myapp-back
  name: myapp-back-deployment
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-back
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: myapp-back
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: myprivate.registry.local/myapp-back:2.1.0
          name: myapp-back
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: myapp-back-cm
                  key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: myapp-back-cm
                  key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: myapp-back-secret
                  key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 0.5
              memory: 512Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 0.25
              memory: 256Mi
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 30
```

service definition

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp-back
  name: myapp-back-svc
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: 2022-08-22 11:37
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "8080"
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp-back
  type: ClusterIP
```

Thank you

Comment: You have an ingress that exposes port 80. You're missing one exposing port 9090. I suspect the connection refused is when logging in, you're getting redirected to <ingress-host>:9090? If so, keep in mind your ingress controllers probably listen on 80/443 only: if you want to involve another backend, either you want to use path-based Ingress routing (/ goes to service A, /backend/ goes to service B), or use separate ingresses, each with their own host/fqdn. btw: might be usefull to include logs from your browser / networking especially, which URLs are called, which request failed, ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's exactly how you say, the backend runs on the same URL but with a different port and it redirected to <ingress-host>:9090/Back-0.0.1 I couldn't figure out how to configure my ingress controller to add this route I'll try to add a prefix /back-0.0.1 and expose port 9090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by using a subdomain for my backend service it seems that I can't use ports here and to be honnest it's better with dns

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-front-ingress
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myapp.mydomain.local
      secretName: myapp-front-tls
  rules:
    - host: myapp.mydomain.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-front-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: api.mydomain.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-back-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Regards